# Approximation of an integrable function by continuous function with an extra criteria.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, approximation

Let $f :[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying 
$$\int_0^1|f(t)|dt<\infty .$$

We know that for given $\epsilon >0$ there exists a continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$ such that $$\|f-g\|_{L^1([0,1])}<\epsilon .$$

Question: Can we find a continuous function $g$ satisfying above such that $Z(f)\subseteq Z(g)$?

($Z(f)$ is the zero set of $f$)

Edit: After comments I changed from $f\in L^1([0,1])$ to above.

Comment: Functions in $L^{1}$ are only defined almost everywhere. So zero set of $f$ is not a well defined set.

Comment: You probably meant something a llittle different for $f$, as pointed out by the other comment. Can you clarify ?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy sir, I edited the question.

Comment: The change you made does not allow for approximation by a continous function, as pointed out by @KaviRamaMurthy. Please be careful about your questions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f=I_A$ where $A$ is the set of all irrational numbers on $[0,1]$. If such a continuous function $g$ exists for some $\epsilon <1$ then $g(x)=0$ for all rational $x$. But $g$ is continuous, so $g(x)=0$ for all $x$. Hence $1=\int f= \int |f-g| <\epsilon$, a  contradiction.

Comment: Sir basically what you did is change the $1_{[0,1]}$  function at a measure set $\mathbb{Q}$ which is also dense in $[0,1]$. That leads me to ask another question: If $f$ vanishes on a set of positive measure then can we get a $g$ such that $g$ also vanishes on a  set of positive measure?